# Find and replace, reusing token, in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I'm having trouble crafting the appropriate find/replace regex to use in Vim.

Here's some SQL:

```
select avg(field_name1), avg(field_name2), avg(field_name3) from a_table
```

Oops, I forgot to alias the results:

```
select avg(field_name1) field_name1,
avg(field_name2) field_name2, avg(field_name3) field_name3 from a_table
```

So, in Vim, I'm sure there's a handy find and replace to match an arbitrary `[a-z]\+_[a-z]\+` inside parenthesis, but I can't figure out how to put that token after the entire match

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following:

```
:s/(\(.*\))/(\1) \1/g
```

Comment: or just `s/(\(.*\))/& \1/g`

Answer (score 7):

Group the text that you want to use in the substitution/replacement with surrounding `\(\)`, and refer to these back-references in the substitution using `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Using `[:alnum:]` to match alphanumeric characters:

```
:s/(\([[:alnum:]]\+_[[:alnum:]]\+\))/(\1) \1/g
```

To apply either regex to the entire file, use:

```
:%s/(\([[:alnum:]]\+_[[:alnum:]]\+\))/(\1) \1/g
```

See also `:help \1` for more details about using back-references.